# Is it correct for VSTS (online) builds to allways do a rebuild all?

Tags: build, azure-devops

I have my code in vsts (visual studio online) and configured a build definition for continuous integration. What i found is, that upon each check in, the build will create/get a new vm, and because of that, it needs to to a get-latest that fetches everything and a complete rebuild. While i understand it's good to have a mode where you rebuild from scratch, for the continuous integration i'd rather have it do a "build" instead of a "rebuild all". This has to do with the cost for the build. a simple rebuild all from scratch in my case takes ~ 16 minutes. So considering the way my team is checking in code, i'd end up with ~200 bucks a months, just for builds. i find this to be a little excessive.

I have been in contact with pss for that, and my contact insist that the way this operates is the only way i can operate. (i have doubts, because there are "clean" options in the build definitions which wouldn't make any sense incase every build would be from scratch anyways.). So do you know if the pss contact is correct and everything actually needs to be rebuild from scratch every single time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when using the Hosted build agents, that is what I would expect.

So, why have "Clean" options, etc? Because TFS Build doesn't have to be run on the Hosted Build Agents, you can host your own build server and do what you like on it.

For example, you can stand up an Azure IAAS VM and run the builds on one agent on that where all you do is "get latest" and build.

Why do the Hosted build agents spin up each time? I'd guess it is the cloud mentality of only pay for what you use. MS don't want to keep VM affinity with customers, which makes sense, as they don't know how many servers you need, how often they are needed.